# Eloquent checkbox search query using multiple parents & or clauses

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, search, eloquent

I have a stock list of around 5,000 items to filter using multiple checkboxes. Some of the checkboxes will be `OR` clauses and some won't. My search checkboxes are broken up into categories for example;

**Type**
`Car, Truck, SUV`

**Make**
`BMW, Audi, RangeRover, Ford`

**Model**
`Data based on previous search criteria database-driven, unknown how many checkboxes or their names`

I've started my query something like this following;

`$StocklistItem = $StocklistItem->newQuery();`

```
// Search based on type.
if ($request->has('car')) {
    $StocklistItem->orWhere('car', 1);
}

if ($request->has('truck')) {
    $StocklistItem->orWhere('productType', 1);
}
```

This works fine but when I apply the 2nd group of filters:

```
// Search based on model. 
if ($request->has('BMW')) {
    $StocklistItem->orWhere('productMake', 'BMW');
}
```

`return $StocklistItem->get();`

Now the search doesn't work because both groups use `orWhere`. I was thinking of having hidden inputs within each group and if a selection was made within that group updating that hidden input. So I could start to group each category of filters and possibly have their "child" checkboxes stored in an array.

Would that be a suitable approach to build up a dynamic search query like this?

Comment: Why you are using `orWhere`,if you are checking condition then you can use `where` clause.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... Because you can have select multiple from the same category. So it's not items `where = Car & truck` it's `where = car or truck`